# iOS kernel overview!

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need an overview of the iOS architecture (Process management, system memory management, kernel) (just an overview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS is very similar to Mac OS X at the kernel level. The major differences would revolve around sandboxing, application privileges, etc. If you're curious about stuff that isn't necessarily iOS-specific, the [Kernel Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Architecture/Architecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH1g-CACDAEDC) provides an overview for a lot of Mach and BSD concepts, like the virtual memory system, how thread scheduling works, etc.